# collapse a list of unevaluated expressions to single expression

Tags: r, metaprogramming

Having the following list of unevaluated expressions.

```
l = list(quote(f()),quote(g()),quote(h()))
str(l)
#List of 3
# $ : language f()
# $ : language g()
# $ : language h()
```

I would like to collapse the list using `&` function so I would get following `r` result.

```
r = quote(f() & g() & h())
str(r)
# language f() & g() & h()
```

Of course the point is to handle list of any length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Reduce` for this:

```
Reduce(function(a,b) bquote(.(a) & .(b)), l)
```